# Как сверстать такие кнопки?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно сверстать такие кнопки?

Они должны быть на всю ширину контейнера, но задавать каждой кнопке разный класс и делать фикс ширину думаю неправильно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Количество кнопок фиксированное?

Comment: Дайте родителю `width: 100%; height: fit-content; display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(/* количество иконок */, auto);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `flex-grow: 1`.

```css
*, ::before, ::after
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu__wrapper
{
  display: flex;
  
  list-style: none;
}

.menu__item
{
  flex-grow: 1;

  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu__item:not(:last-child)
{
  border-right: 2px solid #EFEFEF;
}

.menu__item:hover
{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ACACAC;
}

.menu__item--active
{
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom-color: #6E978F;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu__wrapper">
    <li class="menu__item menu__item--active">Металлопрокат</li>
    <li class="menu__item">Заборы и ограждения</li>
    <li class="menu__item">Кровля</li>
    <li class="menu__item">Профнастил</li>
    <li class="menu__item">Фасад</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Хотелось бы спросить у более разбирающихся в BEM, правильно ли названы элементы? Нужно ли вообще для `<nav>` давать класс?

Comment: Получается что если радитель menu первый потомок menu_wrapper то пункты меню menu_wrapper-item вроде

Comment: Через "__" в моем случае элементы, а не блоки.

Comment: Я порядок написал...а не два пробела или тире ...

Comment: Но пункты меню это элементы блока menu, а ul просто обвертка которая не является самостоятельным.